# QWebFrame object has no attribute documentElement

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit, xvfb

My code:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *



class Browser(QWebView):
  def __init__(self):
    QWebView.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

  def _result_available(self, ok):
    doc = self.page().mainFrame().documentElement()

    [...]



if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  view = Browser()
  view.load(QUrl('http://www.example.net/'))
  app.exec_()
```

For some reason I get this error and I cannot figure it out why.
I have updated to the latest qtwebkit version and still I get this.
The QT manual said it was implemented in version 4.6 and I have qt version 4.6.2-26.el6_4.

I get the following error from the above code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 15, in _result_available
    doc = self.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
AttributeError: 'QWebFrame' object has no attribute 'documentElement'
```

P.S. I also get this error since upgrading from qtwebkit version 2.0-3.el6 to 2.1.1-1.el6:

```
can't make "generic.orientation" because no QAccelerometer sensors exist
```

Comment: Had a similar error while working with `pyqtSignal` to create custom signals.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not help at all.

Comment: Just saying. I guess it's a bug since the PyQt [reference manual](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebframe.html#documentElement) clearly documents the attribute.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. did you work out the solution?

Comment: No. I have not. I think the repo for Centos is simply missing some stuff. It'l probably get fixed at a future update. Lucky for me this is no longer an emergency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and unfortunately I have discovered that there is a bug in the *Centos* package as far as I can tell. I have run a comparison of the contents of all distributions for that version and they do not match. I will wait for an update of *Centos* that seems to be a bit behind other distributions.